# Uninstall Internet Explorer 7/downgrade to Internet Explorer 6 in Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, sp3, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, downgrade

How do I uninstall Internet Explorer 7 from Windows XP SP3 to change it to Internet Explorer 6?

I can't find a good resource for doing so.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JNK no specific reason. Is it possible?

Comment: It is but you need to uninstall SP3 as DMA mentions below - IE7 is wrapped into SP3 and security updates.  I'm asking b/c IE6 is inferior in pretty much every way - very buggy and many security issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927177), which I think tells you exactly what you need to know?

Since you mention SP3, please note that there is an "important" point on there that states:

> **Important** If you installed Windows XP SP3 on your computer after you installed Internet Explorer 7, you need to uninstall Windows XP Service Pack 3 before you can uninstall Internet Explorer 7.

It points to another [Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950719/) to assist with that particular issue.

Comment: +1 - IE7 is integral to SP3 due to the security updates.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

**Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs**

Switch to **Add/Remove Windows Components** and *uncheck* the Internet Explorer checkbox and click **NEXT** and follow through.

Then get Internet Explorer from the Internet, like [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/downloads/critical/ie6sp1/default.mspx) or [here](http://www.brothersoft.com/internet-explorer-60472.html).

This you can use to install or uninstall any Windows component, like Windows Messenger, IIS, printer & faxes, etc.

It's a **standard drill***.

PS: to uninstall, it's fine to install. You will have to insert the Windows XP CD.